# C# XML Query Attributes from specific parent node and add them to children

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

So I have an xml file with the following structure:

```
 <Group Name = "Groceries">
 <Lifetime Creation="2015" Expiration="2018" />
   <Brown Vegetables>
      <Potatoes>
     <LifeTime Creation ="0" Expiration ="0"/>
       </Potatoes>
   </Brown Vegetables>
  <Green Vegetables>
            <Lettuce>
     <LifeTime Creation ="1" Expiration ="1"/>
       </Lettuce>
  <Green Vegetables>
   </Group>
```

So Group Name is considered parent groceries.
I want to take the attribute values from LifeTime from the Group Name containing the name "Groceries",
store them in two integers and add the two integeres to the LifeTime of every child under Groupname Groceries

Output:

```
<Group Name = "Groceries">
 <Lifetime Creation="2015" Expiration="2018" />
   <Brown Vegetables>
      <Potatoes>
     <LifeTime Creation ="2015" Expiration ="2018"/>
       </Potatoes>
   </Brown Vegetables>
  <Green Vegetables>
            <Lettuce>
     <LifeTime Creation ="2016" Expiration ="2019"/>
       </Lettuce>
  <Green Vegetables>
   </Group>
```

The problem is that:
I don't know the full structure of the xml, so there could be some other parent nodes above Group Name. All I know is namespace

I tried something like this::

```
 var value = (from c in doc.Descendants("Position") curr.Attribute("X").Value == "");
```

But all I get is null..so the reading is not correct

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: No. I'm just new to xml parsing

Comment: You are looking for an Element called "Position"? Why?

Comment: My bad, was parsing another xml document and took the line from there. So from what i read from MSDN, Descendants in my case would be Descendands(Group) and curr.Attribute(Creation) and (Expiration) something like that

Comment: Try following : var elements = doc.Descendants().Where(x =>  x.Attributes().Select(y => (string)y == "").Any()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the namespace you're working in so getting elements by name looks a bit messy in the code below. So let me say this clearly, don't just copy and paste this. Use the logic it displays and then create you're own tidier version. Anyway. The code below should do what you want

```
 var groceries = xDoc.Descendants("Group").Where(d => d.Attributes("Name").FirstOrDefault().Value == "Groceries");

        foreach (var grocery in groceries)
        {
            var lifeTimeNode = grocery.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Lifetime");
            var creationYear = int.Parse(lifeTimeNode.Attribute("Creation").Value);
            var expirationYear = int.Parse(lifeTimeNode.Attribute("Expiration").Value);
            var vegetableLifeTimes = grocery.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName != "Lifetime").Select(e => e.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(subE => subE.Name.LocalName == "LifeTime"));
            foreach (var vegLifeTime in vegetableLifeTimes)
            {
                var vegCreationModifier = int.Parse(vegLifeTime.Attribute("Creation").Value);
                var vegExpirationModifier = int.Parse(vegLifeTime.Attribute("Expiration").Value);

                var newExpiration = expirationYear + vegExpirationModifier;
                var newCreation = creationYear + vegCreationModifier;

                vegLifeTime.Attribute("Creation").Value = newCreation.ToString();
                vegLifeTime.Attribute("Expiration").Value = newExpiration.ToString();
            }
        }
```

One thing bear in mind is that the XML you posted isn't actually valid, there are spaces in element names and I'm pretty sure thats not aloud.

So the above code works with the XML in this format

```
<Group Name="Groceries">
  <Lifetime Creation="2015" Expiration="2018" />   
  <BrownVegetables>
    <Potatoes>
      <LifeTime Creation ="0" Expiration ="0"/>
    </Potatoes>
  </BrownVegetables>
  <GreenVegetables>
    <Lettuce>
      <LifeTime Creation="1" Expiration="1"/>
    </Lettuce>
    </GreenVegetables>
</Group>
```